# executar função em content de before e after

Tags: jquery

Tenho um **before** e **after** em uma **div** com seus respectivos **contents**.

Gostaria de **clicar** nesse **content** e executar uma função **jQuery**.

É possível?

Tentei da forma abaixo mas não funcionou nem o `alert`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $(".slideShow ul:nth-child(1)::before").on("click", function() {    
      alert();
          index = $(this).index() + 1;
          $(".slideShow ul:nth-child(1) li").css("display","none");
          $(".slideShow ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child("+index+")").css("display","block");
      });   
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideShow">
  <ul>
    <li><img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" /></li>
    <li><img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*outline: none;*/
    border: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
.aberturaSelect {
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease 2s;
    -moz-transition: 3s ease 2s;
    -o-transition: 3s ease 2s;
    transition: 3s ease 2s;
}
.slideShow {
    width: 100%;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1)::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 150px;
    content: url(_imgs/setaEsquerda.jpg);
    opacity: 0;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1)::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 150px;
    content: url(_imgs/setaDireita.jpg);
    opacity: 0;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1):hover::before, 
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1):hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1) li {
    display: none;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(1) li img {
    width: 100%;
}
.slideShow ul:nth-child(2) li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Não tem como manipular pseudo-elementos com JS.

Comment: algum outro recurso? Algo com CSS talvez?

Comment: Não só mesmo colocando os elementos no html manualmente. Veja [esta pergunta relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Comment: Vc pode alterar a classe. Crie classes com ::before e altere usando jQuery.

Comment: Ex.: `.div_visivel::before { display: block; }` e `.div_oculta::before { display: none; }`

Comment: Aí no jQuery vc faz a troca de uma por outra no elemento.

Comment: Não entendo como isso pode ajudar: eu preciso é executar uma função jQuery. Pode explicar melhor fazendo favor?

Comment: Poste na pergunta o CSS dessa ::before.

Comment: feito. coloquei no final da pergunta

Comment: Vi que vc botou as setas como :after e :before. O melhor é fazer isso com span, pq vc pode capturar clicks nelas. Fiz um JSFiddle com alterações no seu código, no CSS e no JS (as imagens botei qualquer uma só pra ilustrar): https://jsfiddle.net/tgs5m6a2/

Comment: Como o seus pseudo-elementos estão posicionados, dá até para calcular onde estão e comparar com a posição do clique. Mas se for possível use elementos html de verdade que tudo fica mais simples.